# UWP / WinRT Generate Path from multiple rects

Tags: c#, xaml, geometry, winrt-xaml, uwp

How I can create a custom path from two or more rectangles?
I am working with xaml / UWP and the fill color have to transparent.

Current State;
[image]

Needed State;
[image]

Currently I am using following code:

```
GeometryGroup path = new GeometryGroup();
path.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry() { Rect = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100) });
path.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry() { Rect = new Rect(30, 30, 150, 100) });
Data = path;


<Path HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10"
Data="{Binding Data}"
Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="5" Opacity="1" />
```

Comment: I never do this stuff in codebehind, just xaml, but one easy way is just use Blend, select both in the designer, right-click, and choose Path->Unite

Comment: Thats not a solution for me. I need a solution with binding and dynamic count of rects.

Comment: In WPF you could use a CombinedGeometry. However, as far as I know there is nothing like that in UWP, so you have to calculate the resulting geometry yourself.

Comment: Do you know exaplames about the calculation? Maybe in other language or so? Because I didn't find anything with Google :(